# I want to ask a question about the passive

Tags: passive-voice

This is the active sentence:

> "Miss May taught me to draw the Christmas cards."

So how to transform it into the passive one?

Help me please.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To convert an active voice sentence into the passive voice, you find the principal verb - in this case *taught* - and take its object - in this case *me*. That object becomes the subject in the passive voice (and turns into *I*, obviously).

You then put the verb *to be* in the same tense/aspect as the principal verb, or sometimes an appropriate tense/aspect with similar meaning, so in this case we want the simple past - *was*. Now we have *I was*.

Then you take the principal verb of the original sentence, and you get its past participle. In this case, the simple past and past participle are the same, so we keep *taught*. We have *I was taught*.

Then we take the subject of the original sentence, and create an adverbial to indicate that they were the one who did the teaching. This is usually a *by* adverbial, as it is in this case. The adverbial we want is *by Miss May*. Now we've got *I was taught by Miss May*.

But the original sentence has another adverbial! Well, adverbial or indirect object, or various other terms, depending on who you ask; in any case, another phrase that modifies the activity. We still have *to draw the Christmas cards*. This one's easy, you just slot it into the appropriate point in the sentence, and you get:

> I was taught to draw the Christmas cards by Miss May.

The same process applies pretty directly for any active sentence, but it can get pretty complex. You have to get a sense of where any existing adverbials or object complements, descriptive gerunds etc have to go in the end, before or after the *by*-adverbial, and you have to get a sense of the times when you have to change the aspect (form) of the verb in some way - passivising progressives can be a minefield in terms of producing natural sentences. However, at its heart, this is the process you will always use.